# Service is non-existant? Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, service

I'm trying to get this simple notification service working and I am having no joy at all. I've never used services in symfony before so I could be overlooking something pretty basic, however it all seems correct to me so I'm kind of banging my head against a wall here.

I've included everything to do with the service, help would be really appreciated!

**Stack Trace:**

```
[1] Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "game.notify".
    at n/a
        in D:\web\www\mygame\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 1968

    at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('game.notify')
        in D:\web\www\mygame\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 252

    at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->get('game.notify')
        in D:\web\www\mygame\src\Game\MainBundle\Controller\PageController.php line 10

    at Game\MainBundle\Controller\PageController->indexAction()
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(PageController), 'indexAction'), array())
        in D:\web\www\mygame\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2843

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in D:\web\www\mygame\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2817

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in D:\web\www\mygame\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2946

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in D:\web\www\mygame\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2248

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in D:\web\www\mygame\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

**Notify Controller:**

Located at: Game/MainBundle/Controller/NotifyController.php

```
<?php
namespace Game\MainBundle\Controller;

class NotifyController
{
    private $defaults
        = array(
            "type" => "flash",
        ),
        $flashes = array();
    /**
    * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session $session
    */
    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
    /**
    * Depending on the supplied type argument, add the values
    * to the session flashBag or $this->flashes
    *
    * @param string $name
    * @param array $arguments
    */
    public function add($name, array $arguments = array())
    {
        $arguments += $this->defaults;
        // If the type is flash then add the values to the session flashBag
        if ($arguments["type"] === "flash") {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add($name, $arguments);
        }
        // Otherwise if its instant then add them to the class variable $flashes
        elseif ($arguments["type"] === "instant") {
            // We want to be able to have multiple notifications of the same name i.e "success"
            // so we need to add each new set of arguments into an array not overwrite the last
            // "success" value set
            if (!isset($this->flashes[$name])) {
                $this->flashes[$name] = array();
            }
            $this->flashes[$name][] = $arguments;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Check the flashBag and $this->flashes for existence of $name
    *
    * @param $name
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function has($name)
    {
        if($this->session->getFlashBag()->has($name)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return isset($this->flashes[$name]);
        }
    }
    /**
    * Search for a specific notification and return matches from flashBag and $this->flashes
    *
    * @param $name
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function get($name)
    {
        if($this->session->getFlashBag()->has($name) && isset($this->flashes[$name])){
            return array_merge_recursive($this->session->getFlashBag()->get($name), $this->flashes[$name]);
        } elseif($this->session->getFlashBag()->has($name)) {
            return $this->session->getFlashBag()->get($name);
        } else {
            return $this->flashes[$name];
        }
    }
    /**
    * Merge all flashBag and $this->flashes values and return the array
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function all()
    {
        return array_merge_recursive($this->session->getFlashBag()->all(), $this->flashes);
    }

}
```

**NotifyExtension.php**

Located at: Game/MainBundle/DependencyInjection/NotifyExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace Game\MainBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class NotifyExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

**Configuration.php**

Located at: Game/MainBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

```
<?php

namespace Game\MainBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('game_main');

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**Services.yml**
Located at: Game/MainBundle/Resources/Config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    game.notify.class:  Game\MainBundle\Controller\NotifyController

services:
    game.notify:
        class: "%game.notify.class%"
        arguments:
            session: @session
```

**PageController.php**

Located at: Game/MainBundle/Controller/PageController.php

```
<?php
namespace Game\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $notify = $this->get("game.notify");
        $notify->add("test", array("type" => "instant", "message" => "This is awesome"));
        if ($notify->has("test")) {
            return array("notifications" => $notify->get("test"));
        }
        return $this->render('GameMainBundle:Page:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: Stick a die statement to confirm that your NotifyExtension::load is actually being called.  I don't think you are following the correct naming convention.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't do anything at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your answer to my first comment, it would appear that your services are never being loaded due to not following the naming convention for your extension class.

If you have a GameMainBundle for your bundle then you should have GameMainExtension for your extension.

More info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

You might still have some problems once you get services.yml loaded.  Calling your service a controller is a bit non-standard.  But see what happens.